# Combining Spring constructor dependency injection with simple argument

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean

I have a prototype bean that autowires a bean in the constructor:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyClass {

    // Autowired annotation not needed in Spring 5
    public MyClass(UserRepository userRepository) {
    }

}
```

This bean is created with:

```
MyClass myClass = beanFactory.getBean(MyClass.class);
```

This all goes fine. But now I want to include a parameter when I create the bean:

```
MyClass myClass = beanFactory.getBean(MyClass.class, "just-a-string");

// Bean constructor:

public MyClass(String str, UserRepository userRepository) {
}
```

But this results in the following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'myClass' ... Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

How should I combine constructor dependency injection with simple arguments?

**Edit**

As the error indicates, no matching constructor is found. When I use this to create to bean:

```
MyClass myClass = beanFactory.getBean(MyClass.class, "just-a-string", null);
```

The bean is created with success, but of course I'm getting a null pointer later.

**Edit 2**

If I used field injection this situation would be avoided, but as I understand field injection is discouraged:

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository

public MyClass(String str) {
}
```

Comment: declare this string in application.properties and then use `@Value` to get it in MyClass. Then you don't need to pass any string

Comment: I've read about the @Value option, but I want the string value to be different for each prototype bean.

Comment: try to make beanFactory get MyClassBuilder then call your MylassBuilder.build(String mandatoryString);

Comment: from where are you calling getBean? can you put that code. YOu can autowire userRepository in that class and pass that to getBean